# Object equality ruby

Tags: ruby

```
'hello'.class == String # => true
'hello'.class === String # => false
'hello'.class.equal? String # => true
```

As far as I know, the `equal?` method has the strictest comparison test. Can someone explain why `===` returns `false` while `equal?` returns `true` here?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `===` for classes if defined as 'is the class of' (including classes up the hierarchy). For example:

```
String === 'foo' # => true
Class === String # => true
'bar'.class === 'baz' # => true

class A; end
class B < A; end
A === B.new # => true
```